# i don't understand why keycode ==13 is not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, keycode

For some reason my code below is not working even it is identical with someone's code that is actually running ok in chrome. I am using chrom and jquery 1.10.1
the keycode just doesn't fire.

http://jsfiddle.net/2m36v/

```
<ul id="tasks"></ul>
<input type="text" id="taskText" >

$(function() {
    $('#taskText').keydown(function(evt) {
        if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
            var taskText = this.value;
            $('<li>').text(taskText).appendTo('#tasks');
            $(this).val() = "";
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is that the right fiddle? The code there doesn't match the code here.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo:  `$(this).val() = "";`  Firebug shows that Chrome is throwing a parse error, so the script will not run at all.  You need of course:

```
$(this).val("");
```

[(Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/4bhX8/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Change it

```
$(this).val() = "";
```

to

```
this.value="";
```

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4bhX8/4/)